# Dual Citizenship and the ESTA Program

Tags: usa, esta, dual-nationality

I have dual citizenship in both the UK and South Africa and intend on visiting the US in November. On the ESTA website there is a section referring to dual citizenship, should I declare my South African Citizenship even though it is not under the VWP program?

Answer (score 5):

Let's split this into two.

1. [Do I need to apply for ESTA?](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1094/%7E/do-i-need-to-apply-for-esta%3F)

> I have dual citizenship from both a VWP country and a non-VWP country?
>
> If you are flying under the terms of the VWP, with your VWP passport, you must apply for ESTA. If you are using your non-VWP country's passport, you will require a visa and therefore ESTA does not apply to you.

2. Do you need to answer the question? Obviously. You can not skip questions on the ESTA form and as above indicates this is a common case and will not in itself cause refusal of ESTA.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you must declare all citizenships you have or have had.

Some citizenships (though South Africa is not currently among them) will *disqualify* you from using the VWP even if you're *also* a national of a VWP country and traveling on its passport, so they want to know all of them.

Comment: Actually, IIRC they always asked about other citizenships, long before the new restrictions.

Comment: Long? [As of November 3, 2014, the additional questions are](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1756/kw/esta,%20dual%20citizenship/suggested/1) - Other Citizenships. There has been another wave since, yes.

Comment: @Relaxed: Yes -- though I assume the reason the question was always there must have been such that certain citizenships could be flagged for human review. What's new now is just that Congress has officially insisted on _automatically_ excluding certain dual nationals from the VWP, rather than leaving that determination to the DHS.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Not necessarily, it could be to help some form of matching between databases or as a input to a risk assessment algorithm. Either way, we don't really know.